# Conditional null check code lines is not being considered by code coverage

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

If i write code line like

```
string employeeName= objEmp?.EmployeeName;
```

then this line is not being considered by code coverage because of `?.`.
What i will have to do to consider this line by code coverage in .net core.

Comment: Are you certain it's because of `?.`? If you change it to a traditional `if` block is it covered?

Comment: please review the microsoft article on code coverage : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/using-code-coverage-to-determine-how-much-code-is-being-tested?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 0):

the code coverage should include two condition for this line of code, when objEmp is null and not null,

your line of code translates to this :

```
if objEmp is null
   employeeName = null
else 
   employeeName = objEmp.employeeName
```

so you need two unit tests to cover the two conditions

Answer (score -1):

string employeeName = objEmp?.EmployeeName ?? string.Empty;

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

What you're looking for is called the null-coalescing operator and has two common forms: ?? and ??= (assignment) which can be used as shown:

```
var employeeName = objEmp.EmployeeName ?? Value
```

This will set employeeName to Value if objEmp.Employee is null

```
var employeeName ??= obj.EmployeeName
```

This will set employeeName to obj.EmployeeName if employeeName is null (which will always be the case in this instance since employeeName is just declared)

The first option seems to make most sense for your case but doesn't hurt to know both.

Some useful documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator

Comment: How do you know that's what they're looking for? What happens if `objEmp` is `null`?